# The "SHOW COLUMNS" query in PHP doesn't show first row

Tags: php, mysql, apache, lamp

Happy Holidays everyone

I am new to PHP so any assistance would greatly appreciated.

I am, like a lot of people, working on a web site with PHP and mysql access and I am seeking to write a page where I can set or adjust my site parameters and store them in a mysql table called "Unit_parameters".

What I am seeking to do is to use the "SHOW COLUMNS" mysql query to get the "Field" name and its associated "Type" and then write PHP code to automatically insert a certain form element according to what field type it is. For example I would like to insert a check box if the field type is a boolean, or a short text box for an INT, etc.

In the process of trying to get my field listing to *SIMPLY* display in a browser page I have found that PHP is leaving off the first line of results from my query, which represents the first column of my Unit_parameters table.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
$currentDB =& connectToDB();  // Connection is made using PHPs PDO method.
$para = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Unit_parameters";
$table_fields = $currentDB->query($para);
foreach($table_fields as $field)
{
    echo $field["Field"] . "&nbsp;"; // The space and break are to make it
    echo $field["Type"] . "<br />";  // so that it is not all on one line
}                                    // in my browser and run together.
$currentDB = NULL;
```

What am I doing wrong? I have done a search of Stackoverflow and found a few procedures to get what I want done except they use methods that the PHP web site states are "Depreciated". I'm leaning rather strongly in the direction of not using depreciated methods so I won't have to rewrite my site later when those methods are removed in future PHP releases.

Again, any assistance would greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Walt Williams

I am using PHP 5.4, Apache 2.2, and mysql 5.5

Comment: what exactly is happening in this `->query()` method? Because as-written, there is no way for the above code to skip anything. So show what ->query() is doing.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the `query()` method. Maybe it's calling `fetch()` followed by `fetchAll()`, and not putting the row used by `fetch()` back into the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, so you don't have to rely on the implicit statement iterator. It may well be fouled up for convenience queries.

```
$q = $currentDB->query($para);
while ($field = $q->fetch())
{
    echo $field["Field"] . "&nbsp;"; // The space and break are to make it
    echo $field["Type"] . "<br />";  // so that it is not all on one line
}
```

Also, I suggest you use the [MySQL `information_schema` pseudo-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html) to retrieve this kind of information.  You get a lot more control over the results than you would for a simple `SHOW COLUMNS` convenience query. Try this SQL statement, for example.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS   
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'Unit_parameters'
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$currentDB =& connectToDB();  // Connection is made using PHPs PDO method.
$para = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Unit_parameters";
$res=mysql_query("show columns from emp1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo $row["Field"] . "&nbsp;"; // The space and break are to make it
    echo $row["Type"] . "<br />";  // so that it is not all on one line
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's wise to abandon the newer and safer PDO interface in favor of the older and deprecated mysql_ interface.